# Magento 2 - Programatically updating the inventory store wise not working

Tags: product, magento2.2, price, inventory

I have a function to update the product inventory progrmmatically.below is my function in the helper file.

```
protected $stockRegistry;
...
public function __construct(
.... //Some code--
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry) {
     $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}  
public function updateStockAndPricesByStore($productId,$store_data,$sku)
{
    $productFactory = $this->_productFactory->create();

        foreach($store_data as $store){
            $store_datas = explode("-",$store);

            $store_id = $store_datas[0];
            $qty = $store_datas[1];
            $price = $store_datas[2];

            $this->productResourceModel->load($productFactory, $productId);
            $productFactory->setStoreId($store_id);
            $productFactory->setPrice($price);
            $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($productFactory, 'price');

            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku, $store_id);
            //$stockItem->setStoreId($store_id);
            $stockItem->setQty($qty);
            echo "Stock Also Updated";
            $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty); // this line
            $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
        }        
}
```

This is my array i am passing as `$store_data`.

> Array ( [0] => 1-11-11 [1] => 2-22-22 ) - (store_id - qty - price)

Whenever updating for both stores, last qty updated to both store but price is correctly updating .

How can i update the inventory store wise programatically in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 Qty field is **a global field**. So, you can not update the qty at store view/website label.

You want to store view qty then you have to do customization or you have to use any 3rd party extension.